# Angular JS with MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I want to know if `Angular JS` can be used with `ASP.NET MVC` architecture in any way? I have tried searching on Google, but can't figure out if `Angular JS` is usable in `.cshtml` page of `ASP.NET MVC` and is it the good idea to use it?

Comment: Yes it can be used with MVC. See my latest answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29813897/how-to-load-html-page-in-mvc-5-for-angularjs-routing/29814476#29814476

Answer (score 2):

you can definitely use AngularJs with Asp.Net MVC as it is a client side framework which entirely runs in the browser. It doesn't depend on any of the Asp.Net features as such. There are lot of samples available online. Here is a [channel 9 video](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/NorthAmerica/2014/DEV-B420) which guides you through

Answer (score 0):

From the official ASP.net pages: [Hands On Lab: Build a Single Page Application (SPA) with ASP.NET Web API and Angular.js](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/build-a-single-page-application-%28spa%29-with-aspnet-web-api-and-angularjs)

The fact that is uses WebAPI shouldn't really matter here, as that's a detail matter of implementation. AngularJS works fine on top of either.

First hit on google...

Answer (score 0):

If you looking to achieve CRUD in your application I recommend this post as a guide to follow. Even though this uses WEB API, its still a good way of getting to grips with angularjs.

Hope this helps.

[CRUD with SPA, ASP.NET Web API and Angular.js](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/832288/CRUD-with-SPA-ASP-NET-Web-API-and-Angular-js)